# Cannot open Android NDK project

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a project on the host (`Windows 7 x64, Eclipse Juno, ADT 21.1, CDT 21.1, NDK r8e`). When i moved the project to my laptop, it turned out that he was not properly open.
`C` and `Java` source code, and configuration are handled correctly, 
but in the `.CPP` file and `.H` file (jni/ folder) 
i have error `"undefined reference jni.h"`.

Although the system will check the settings for installing VMware virtual system, the same situation. Systems are configured identically, environment variables are set. New projects created on a laptop or a VMware going normally.

Comment: can you post the error that you get on the laptop and the laptop configuration?

Comment: Windows 7 x86, environment variables, Android SDK, NDK and IDE identically of the host. Sorry, a bit confused mistake. Error is "unresolved inclusion" and as you can see, java variables also does not define http://mirror2.upwap.ru/d/3061395/d2da6ee5fb5e6118b9f2a1005152d7f9/Untitled.jpg

Comment: I did commit to SVN (Tortoise) from the host. Made a copy on my laptop from SVN. Open the project in Eclipse via File-> Import

Comment: it should be a correct procedure. try to use the eclipse for java (see my answer below) and see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image you sent in the comment, it seems that you are using Eclipse for Android development. 
Try to download the [java version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr2) and use that one instead (for instance, the same used in you host: Eclipse Juno, ADT 21.1, CDT 21.1, NDK r8e).

I had a similar problem and it was due to the Eclipse version.